# Generic relation for database

Tags: database, inheritance, database-design, schema, entity-relationship

I have to design a generic entity that would be able to refer to variated other entities.

In my example, that would be a `commentary` entity inside a web application. You could post commentaries on to `users`, `classifieds`, `articles`, `varieties` (botanical ones), and so on.

So that entity would be made like this:

[image: Commentary entity that targets any entity/record]

As a matter of fact, the design (kind of) pattern would be this one:
[image: Generic entity]

What are the pros and cons of this kind of pattern?

What I see is:

### Pros

- It decreases the number of entities if the concept is the same (commentaries for example);
- You can therefore easily manipulate heterogeneous objects;
- You can aggregate these objects easily (e.g. this user's last commentaries in the whole site, presented easily in a same thread);

  ### Cons
- This allows you to fall in the ugly (you use it outrageously and your database and source code are ugly);
- There is no control in the database, and this one must therefore be done inside the application code.
- What are the performances impacts?

### Conclusion

Is this kind of pattern suitable for a relational database? How can we do then?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic Polymorphic Association anti-pattern. There are a number of possible solutions:

**1)** Exclusive Arcs e.g. for the Commentary entity

```
Id
User_Id
Classified_Id
Article_Id
Variety_Id
```

Where User_Id, Classified_Id, Article_Id and Variety_Id are nullable and exactly one must be not null.

**2)** Reverse the Relationship e.g remove the Target_Entity and Target_Entity_Id from the Commentary entity and create four new entities

User_Commentary

```
Commentary_Id
User_Id
```

Classified_Commentary

```
Commentary_Id
Classified_Id
```

Article_Commentary

```
Commentary_Id 
Article_Id
```

Variety_Commentary

```
Commentary_Id
Variety_Id
```

Where Commentary_Id is unique and relates to the Id in Commentary.

**3)** Create a super-type entity for User, Classified, Article and Variety and have the Commentary entity reference the unique attribute of this new entity.

You would need to decide which of these approaches you feel is most appropriate in your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks. 1) is interestinr in my case. 2) would allow a same commentary to be put on several entities. 3) seems good, although the erd would become a spaghetti dish.

Comment: Could you also explain why my pattern is not fine?

Comment: You have identified the pros and cons in your question. I have offered some standard alternatives for this situation. The main one I would mention is that your conceptual model would not produce a relational data model as `target_entity_id` is not defined over a single domain. The relationships then cannot be standard foreign key constraints, but must be implemented programmatically, which can be complicated when catering for aspects such as like concurrency control. It is up to you to pick the one (from both yours and mine) you feel is your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know already which pattern I shall use, but I understand better.

Answer (score 2):

One more con :

This scheme relies on a mapping between values and names for the "entities" referred to by those values.  Think of all the fun you'll have resolving issues that in the TEST system, the ORDER entity has number 734 but in production, it has number 256.  You can use the entity names themselves as the values of your entity_id stuff, but you will never be able to avoid hardcoding values for them in your programs (or, say, in view definitions) anyway.  Thereby defeating whatever advantage it was you thought you could win.

This kind of scheme is a disease mostly suffered by OO programmers.  They see structures that are largely similar and they have this instinctive reflex "I must find a way to resue the existing thing for this".  Forgetting that database design is not program design.

EDIT

(if it wasn't clear, this means my answer to your question "Is this kind of pattern suitable for a relational database?" is a principled "NO".)

Comment: Thank you also for your answer. Both are enlightening, and now I better see the situation!